# Screen brightness not working (Sony T Series)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

I have a Sony T-Series notebook with an Intel HD 4000 graphics card. I use Ubuntu 12.04. The brightness control of the screen does not work (doesn't matter if I do it with the keyboard or in the system settings). I see the bar that is changing but nothing happens.